# Animate fixed nav from center

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to add an expanding animation to the navbar when it becomes sticky (when the user reaches the waypoint).

For some reason, the transition always jumps to the left side at the beginning instead of expanding from the center.

How can I make it "grow" from where it is?

**HTML:**

```
<header class="header">
  <div class="bg"></div>

  <div id="waypoint"></div>

  <nav class="nav" id="nav">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <ul>
          <li>txt</li>
          <li>txt</li>
          <li>txt</li>
          <li>txt</li>
          <li>txt</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav.sticky .wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: auto;
  background: #d0d0d0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: 1s all ease;
}
```

The **Javascript** just adds the `sticky` class when the user gets to the waypoint.

[JSFiddle demo - what I got so far](https://jsfiddle.net/1htqqfvb/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason, the transition always jumps to the left side at the beginning instead of expanding from the center.

That’s because the default value for `left` and `right` is `auto`, and therefor the “initial” *calculated* left value when you switch to fixed position becomes the one the left element edge had before.

Simply specify `0` for both explicitly, and it should work:

```
.nav.sticky .wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* … */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1htqqfvb/3/

Comment: Thanks! Great, simple solution. However, this caused another problem. If I add images, when the nav turns sticky, they shake in a weird fashion. [Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1htqqfvb/4/). Do you know how to make them stop?